# WSO2 Data Services (DSS) and REST resources concepts

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

Hi I may be missing some concepts with WSO2 DSS REST resources.

1. How can I create a resource that supports CRUD operations (same resource name but different verbs)?
   For example, if I have DSS resource '/services/samples/RDBMSSample/employees' I would like to be able to make GET, POST, PUT, DELETE to 'employees' resource, but DSS doesn't allow me to do it - it replaces the resource with whatever the last one is defined.
2. When using JSON to make post to a resource it requires to wrap data in element with the name of operation
   `'{"employeesbynumber":{"employeenumber":{"$":"1002"}}}'`
   I suspect that it is because you are doing internal mapping to SOAP in DSS. Is there a way around it?
3. What is the correct way to use endpoint. In TryIt tool there are several available endpoint for SOAP1.1, SOAP1.2. HttpEndpoint. As well as there is endpoint without suffix. What is the right approach to reference them from clients?

Thank you!

Comment: For P2: this is limitation of Axis2 REST when it internally maps input request to SOAP message style... At least in 1.6.1

Answer (score 0):

You can refer http://docs.wso2.org/display/DSS310/Exposing+Data+as+REST-Style+Resources to achieve the REST CRUD operations on your data.

Also you can try out your endpoint in any of the available endpoints in the tryit tool.

Thanks
Manisha